# Open problems with practical outcome in a visible future?

Tags: open-problem

[Note] The question has been asked at Matheoverflow. But there is no answers.

I believe that any non-trivial idea will sooner or later find application in real life.
However "sooner" is better than "later":)

If we look at famous open problems - e.g. Millennium Prize problems - there is no clear
practical outcome from their solution (imho). (Well, P vs NP of course will be of greatest importance if one will produce quick algrorithm to solve all NP problems - but it seems it is not plausible).

**Question** what are open problems which solution will have some "real life" outcome in **visible future** ?

---

My answer. It might be not perfect from various sides,  but still...

**Problem** Construction of **short** and effective error-correcting codes.

**Background**
Recent advances in error-corrrecting codes are LDPC and turbo-codes  - invented in 90-ies
(more recent polar codes)
produced codes which are highly effective for quite a **long** length of the codewords
(thousands bits or may be even dozens thousands). These codes are widely used in practive,
e.g. 3G-smart-phones use turbo-codes. (See wikipedia articles on turbo-codes and LDPC)

However such codes are not effective for short sequences of bits (dozens bits).
That is why a problem.

**Practical importance** 
In cell networks not only data is transmitted, but various auxilliary information
- e.g. acknowledge receipts (data has been received or not), various channel quality indicators (measuring how bad are propogation conditions).
Amount of such data is not big - dozens of bits - so we need short codes.
Up to recent times this was not considered as important issue, because it might be just 1% of data transmission. But with the advance of smartphones and "always on-line"
feature this appears to be critical problem. 
Since "always on-line" means sending very often and very short amounts of data, but for each data transmission one needs to send also auxilliary information - so 
the amount of auxilliary information becomes comparable with data transmission.

**Literature**
This problem is mentioned in influential article in telecommunication community 
"Is the PHY layer dead?" http://repositori.upf.edu/handle/10230/13026

("PHY(=physical) layer" - is a part where most mathematical-consuming
algorithms were concentrated (e.g. error-correcting codes, statstical algorithms for 
signal estimation etc.)). So the title has a flavor  "math is not useful  for wireless telecom anymore?" (However now RM (Resource managament) layer is consuming math (from game theory to optimization) so we may not worry :).

Comment: Finding a (fast, practical) polynomial-time factoring algorithm would break RSA, turn public key cryptography on its head, and cause me to stop using online banking for the moment.

Comment: Is this question on-topic?

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: Well it fits the chosen tag, and I'm also interested to know some answers. RSA would simply be replaced by something else in the meantime.. Theoretically RSA is broken by Shor's algorithm but I've yet to hear of a practical quantum computer.

Comment: If somebody want to ask about Shor's alorithm do so via a question not viacreating debates in comments.